# How to run an android Adobe AIR app on PC (without using emulators)?

Tags: android, air, flash, apk

I have an Adobe AIR app wrapped inside a android `.apk` file.
There are these 6 files and folders inside this `.apk` file:

```
assets/
lib/
res/
smali/
AndroidManifest.xml
apktool.yml
```

Inside `assets/` there are these 6 files and folders:

```
assets/
icons/
META-INF/
adobeair.vch
CardLoader.swf
UPPayPluginEx.apk
```

If I double click `CardLoader.swf`, IE will open with a black screen. Right click the black screen, in the context menu it says `Movie not loaded`. I guess I need to pass in some arguments when I start `CardLoader.swf`, or there are some other libraries I need to import before starting it.

So my question is, given an Adobe AIR app, what is the proper way to start it on PC? Also, is there a debug mode with log, so I can see what has gone wrong?

FYI: the contents inside `AndroidManifest.xml` is

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest android:versionCode="1004003" android:versionName="1.4.3" android:installLocation="auto" package="air.com.ifree.cardCHS"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
                <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.NoShadow" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".AppEntry" android:launchMode="standard" android:screenOrientation="user" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
                    <meta-data android:name="namespaceVersion" android:value="4.0" />
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    <meta-data android:name="aspectRatio" android:value="landscape" />
                    <meta-data android:name="autoOrients" android:value="true" />
                    <meta-data android:name="fullScreen" android:value="true" />
                    <meta-data android:name="uniqueappversionid" android:value="f7d78b5c-2b5e-4f6c-be14-36feb89cb576" />
                    <meta-data android:name="initialcontent" android:value="CardLoader.swf" />
                    <meta-data android:name="containsVideo" android:value="false" />
                </activity>
                <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.shanks.flash.ane.FlashAneNativeActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
                <activity android:name="com.shanks.uploadimage.GalleryActivity" />
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unionpay.uppay.PayActivityEx" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Run" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <data android:scheme="uppay" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.UPPay" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unionpay.uppay.PayActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Run" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <data android:scheme="uppay" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        </manifest>
```

the contents inside `assets/META-INF/AIR/application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">

    <!-- Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template. Specifies parameters 
        for identifying, installing, and launching AIR applications. xmlns - The 
        Adobe AIR namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.3 The last segment 
        of the namespace specifies the version of the AIR runtime required for this 
        application to run. minimumPatchLevel - The minimum patch level of the AIR 
        runtime required to run the application. Optional. -->

    <!-- A universally unique application identifier. Must be unique across 
        all AIR applications. Using a reverse DNS-style name as the id is recommended. 
        (Eg. com.example.ExampleApplication.) Required. -->
    <id>com.ifree.cardCHS</id>

    <!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
    <filename>CardLoader</filename>

    <!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. May have 
        multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <name>mysticalcard</name>

    <!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents 
        application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. Values 
        can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value. 
        An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher 
        than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
    <versionNumber>1.4.3</versionNumber>

    <!-- A string value (such as "v1", "2.5", or "Alpha 1") that represents 
        the version of the application, as it should be shown to users. Optional. -->
    <!-- <versionLabel></versionLabel> -->

    <!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer. May have multiple 
        values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <!-- <description></description> -->

    <!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
    <!-- <copyright></copyright> -->

    <!-- Publisher ID. Used if you're updating an application created prior 
        to 1.5.3 -->
    <!-- <publisherID></publisherID> -->

    <!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
    <initialWindow>
        <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
        <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
        <content>CardLoader.swf</content>

        <!-- The title of the main window. Optional. -->
        <!-- <title></title> -->

        <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. 
            Default standard. -->
        <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome 
            is none. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is initially visible. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <visible></visible> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can minimize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <minimizable></minimizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can maximize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <maximizable></maximizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <resizable></resizable> -->

        <!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <width>960</width> -->

        <!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <height>640</height> -->

        <!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <x></x> -->

        <!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <y></y> -->

        <!-- The window's minimum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, 
            such as "400 200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <minSize></minSize> -->

        <!-- The window's initial maximum size, specified as a width/height pair 
            in pixels, such as "1600 1200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <maxSize></maxSize> -->

        <!-- The initial aspect ratio of the app when launched (either "portrait" 
            or "landscape"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation 
            of the device -->

        <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>

        <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile 
            only. Default false -->

        <!-- <autoOrients></autoOrients> -->

        <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default 
            false -->

        <!-- <fullScreen></fullScreen> -->

        <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, gpu, or direct). Optional. 
            Default auto -->

        <!-- <renderMode>gpu</renderMode> -->

        <!-- Whether the default direct mode rendering context allocates storage 
            for depth and stencil buffers. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <depthAndStencil></depthAndStencil> -->

        <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either 
            "pan" or "none"). Optional. Defaults "pan." -->
        <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
        <resizable>false</resizable>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>

    <!-- We recommend omitting the supportedProfiles element, -->
    <!-- which in turn permits your application to be deployed to all -->
    <!-- devices supported by AIR. If you wish to restrict deployment -->
    <!-- (i.e., to only mobile devices) then add this element and list -->
    <!-- only the profiles which your application does support. -->
    <!-- <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice extendedMobileDevice</supportedProfiles> -->

    <!-- Languages supported by application -->
    <!-- Only these languages can be specified -->
    <!-- <supportedLanguages>en de cs es fr it ja ko nl pl pt ru sv tr zh</supportedLanguages> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
    <!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the Programs menu to use. (Ignored on operating systems 
        without a Programs menu.) Optional. -->
    <!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->

    <!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution, 
        specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. -->
    <icon>
        <image29x29>icons/icon_29.png</image29x29>
        <image36x36>icons/icon_36.png</image36x36>
        <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
        <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
        <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
        <image114x114>icons/icon_114.png</image114x114>
        <image512x512>icons/icon_512.png</image512x512>
    </icon>

    <!-- Whether the application handles the update when a user double-clicks 
        an update version of the AIR file (true), or the default AIR application 
        installer handles the update (false). Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <customUpdateUI></customUpdateUI> -->

    <!-- Whether the application can be launched when the user clicks a link 
        in a web browser. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <allowBrowserInvocation></allowBrowserInvocation> -->

    <!-- Listing of file types for which the application can register. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileTypes> -->

    <!-- Defines one file type. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileType> -->

    <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
    <!-- <name></name> -->

    <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
    <!-- <extension></extension> -->

    <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
    <!-- <description></description> -->

    <!-- The MIME content type. -->
    <!-- <contentType></contentType> -->

    <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
    <!-- <icon> <image16x16></image16x16> <image32x32></image32x32> <image48x48></image48x48> 
        <image128x128></image128x128> </icon> -->

    <!-- </fileType> -->
    <!-- </fileTypes> -->

    <!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
    <!-- <iPhone> -->
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
    <!-- <InfoAdditions> <![CDATA[ <key>UIDeviceFamily</key> <array> <string>1</string> 
        <string>2</string> </array> <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
        <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> <string>YES</string> ]]> </InfoAdditions> -->
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Entitlements.plist -->
    <!-- <Entitlements> <![CDATA[ <key>keychain-access-groups</key> <array> 
        <string></string> <string></string> </array> ]]> </Entitlements> -->
    <!-- Display Resolution for the app (either "standard" or "high"). Optional. 
        Default "standard" -->
    <!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
    <!-- </iPhone> -->

    <!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml 
        file. -->
    <!--<android> -->
    <!-- <manifestAdditions> <![CDATA[ <manifest android:installLocation="auto"> 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <uses-feature android:required="true" 
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/> <application android:enabled="true"> 
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> </intent-filter> 
        </activity> </application> </manifest> ]]> </manifestAdditions> -->
    <!-- Color depth for the app (either "32bit" or "16bit"). Optional. Default 
        16bit before namespace 3.0, 32bit after -->
    <!-- <colorDepth></colorDepth> -->
    <!-- </android> -->
    <!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml 
        file -->

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <!--See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information about setting Google Android permissions-->
                <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>-->

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

                <application>
                <activity android:launchMode="standard"> 
                        <intent-filter> 
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
                        </intent-filter> 
                    </activity>

                    <activity android:name="com.shanks.flash.ane.FlashAneNativeActivity" 
                        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
                    </activity>

                    <activity android:name="com.shanks.uploadimage.GalleryActivity">
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    </activity>

                    <activity 
            android:name="com.unionpay.uppay.PayActivityEx"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Run" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="uppay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.unionpay.uppay.PayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UPPay"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Run" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="uppay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                </application>
            </manifest>

        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions>
            <![CDATA[           
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>

            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
<!--                <string>2</string> -->
            </array>
        ]]>
        </InfoAdditions>

        <Entitlements><![CDATA[
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <false/>
            <key>aps-environment</key>
            <string>production</string>
            <key>application-identifier</key>
            <string>8GMLH8G73Q.com.ifree.cardCHS</string>
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
            <string>8GMLH8G73Q.*</string>
            </array>
        ]]></Entitlements>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>

<extensions>
        <extensionID>com.tapjoy.extensions</extensionID>
        <extensionID>net.shanks.ane.flurry</extensionID>
        <extensionID>com.shanks.flash.ane</extensionID>
        <extensionID>com.example.uppayanejava</extensionID>

</extensions>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a stab here, but AIR apps require the AIR runtime in order to run (unless it is iOS where AS3 is fully cross-compiled to Objective-C). It would appear the dev compiled using Captive Runtime (I am assuming `adobeair.vch` is the runtime), so the runtime is included. However, the runtime included is meant to serve as a Flash emulator for Android. I am sure it is written in Java using various Android libraries. This is, I think, why you can't run it. You **must** have that runtime because it was compiled to use it. But that runtime cannot be run in browser, or on anything other than Android.

Again, that is just a guess and I have no proof either way (especially since I have never seen someone even attempt this), but I think it is fairly close to the truth.

Answer (score -2):

You can try installing the android SDK and open an android emulator to run the .apk

Comment: The question explicitly asks how do to so without using emulators.